# HTML5 video buffering despite waiting for `canplaythrough` event to `play()`

Tags: html, video, buffering, mediastream

I'm trying to ensure (to the extent possible) that an HTML5 video begins playing only only when it is able to play through completely without buffering. For context, the MediaStream of the video is then used to mix with another audio source and sent over peer WebRTC connections. The videos are typically 5-10MB and a few minutes long (i.e. a decent broadband connection should have no trouble loading the entire video well before it's done playing).

To achieve this, my code currently waits for the `canplaythrough` event on the video element to begin and calls `play()` when it fires.

This "works" in the sense that the video begins playing and, in most cases, buffering is sufficient for the video to play through uninterrupted. But, in a few cases (specifically for two people so far that happen to both have been running Chrome on MacBook Airs and with apparently not incredible but decent broadband Internet connections) the video plays staggered and choppy---which I believe to mean the video has not sufficiently buffered.

Are there better techniques for either ensuring that video is sufficiently buffered on most browsers?

Would using `fetch()` to buffer the entire video in memory probably do the trick? Or is a resulting `blob()` also actually lazily buffered behind the scenes?

Are there good practices for testing and debugging these sorts of issues given that I can't really replicate this locally?

Comment: We are also seeing this lazy buffering with canplaythrough, annoying

Answer (score 0):

I have built a tool called [Stream or Not](https://dougsillars.github.io/StreamOrNot/) that might help on the network side. It will tell you how long the video takes to start, how many stalls, etc.  You can use your browser's devTools to throttle the network (and in Chrome, you can emulate the CPU).

Honestly - to see if the network is the issue, as long as the bitrate (use FFprobe https://www.streamclarity.com/probe?url=) is lower than the network speed, you are not network constrained.

There is another possibility.  What are the dimensions of your video?  How what are the dimensions of the viewport on the browser?  If you are asking the device to chop down a lot of pixels - the playback limit might move away from bandwidth to CPU processing speed. I have seen this happen on [mobile devices](https://dougsillars.com/2020/03/03/video-playback-on-mobile-devices/) and on older Macs trying to play 4k videos - there just isn't enough CPU to process that many pixels.

1. I'd test the network speeds, just to be sure.
2. Make sure you are not sending more pixels than you need.  Underpowered devices will have issues.